# Can I use BMS to charge 18650 batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I found this cheap 2S BMS module. Website says that is offers over-charge and over-discharge protection. That means I can charge 18650s with it. below is the screen shot. If no, then what should I use with it to charge batteries. I have 2S 18650 battery pack and I want to make it portable (charging/discharging features)

[image]

Comment: Most important word: "cheap"...

Comment: Charge batteries with a battery charger. The BMS protects in case the charger goes haywire or the load tries to over-discharge. If the BMS provides balancing, at least you can use a simple 2S charger without balancing.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't use a BMS to charge batteries, because it is only a BMS and you need a charger to charge batteries. This BMS simply provides overcharge and overdischarge protection.

Comment: In what way overcharge protection comes in handy ? if i am not charging battries with bms then how come it have that feature ? Thank you for the reply

Comment: If the charger is incompatible or you connect batteries directly to a power supply, or the charger is not working properly, the BMS will be the last line of protection for preventing the batteries exploding and/or starting a fire than can burn down houses. That's why battery cells need to have this protection feature somewhere in the system, so when it is in the BMS it enables you to make a safe battery pack wirh BMS and two raw unprotected lithium cells.

Comment: can i use tp4056s with this bms,

Comment: No, because that charges single cell batteries and you are making a two cell battery.

Comment: can i use TP5100 with 2S BMS ? tp5100 is 2S charger

Comment: "In what way overcharge protection comes in handy ?" Same way seatbelts and airbags come in handy in your car. I hope you don't use them as parking aids.